# Why the value a in base class not changing?

Tags: java, variables, inheritance

so I am trying to understand how exactly inheritance works in java. i want to update the value of a in the super class with the help of the method in class two. and I want to print the updated data using the method in class three. But I am not getting the updated data I am still getting 10 as output though I changed it to 20 using the update method in class two. why does this happen? how can I solve this?

code:

```
class one{
    int a=10;
}
 
class two extends one{
    void update(){
        super.a=20;
    }
}

class three extends one{
    void print_changed_data(){
        System.out.println(super.a);
    }
}

public class four{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        two obj2=new two();
        obj2.update();

        three obj3=new three();
        obj3.print_changed_data();
    }
}
```

Comment: it did change, but you changed it for your obj2 instance, not for obj3. Do you understand the difference between static and instance?

Comment: That's not how inheritance works, Class `three` is a new instance that knows nothing about what class `two` did to `a` in its instance. Class `two` and class `three` have different instances of `a`.

Comment: Maybe you want to make the variable a in class one accessible by its subclasses by utilizing the protected keyword?

Comment: @Stultuske can you give me the exact code?

Comment: static int a; in class one

Comment: @LuckyBandit74 not including `protected`, `private` and `public` will mean it's `default` which means it is visible to anything in the same package, so it will already be visible to it's subclasses assuming they are in the same package.

Comment: @JawadElFou yep solved it!. please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @MathewVarkey making it static isn't what inheritance is

Comment: @Popeye I see, I would think it’s good practice to use protected to understand its functionality but that works too

Comment: @LuckBandit74 I would say best practice would be to make it private and create a setter and getter method for accessing the property outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Super is used for accessing a variable or method from the parent class, it can't change the prototype of that class. When you create obj3 it still instantiates off of the original prototype. This is what you end up with in your code:

```
two obj2=new two();
// obj2 = {
//     a = 10
//     update()
// }
obj2.update();
// obj2 = {
//     a = 20
//     update()
// }

three obj3=new three();
// obj2 = {
//     a = 20
//     update()
// }
// obj3 = {
//     a = 10
//     print_changed_data()
// }
```

Here's a better example of what super is used for:

```
class one{
    int a=10;

    void update(){
        a = 30;
    }
}

class two extends one{

    void update(){
        a=20;
    }

    void print(){
        // a = 10
        System.out.println(a);
    
        this.update(); // a = 20
        System.out.println(a);
    
        super.update(); // a = 30
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}

public class three{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        two obj2=new two();
        obj2.print();
        // output
        // 10
        // 20
        // 30
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood what is happening in inheritance between these 3 classes. Each time you create a new instance of class using `new` in your example you are creating a new instance variable called `a` in that class which starts out with the value of 10. In class `Two` you have an instance method called `update()` which changes the value of `a` to 20, calling this method will only update `a` for the class instance you are calling it on; in this case `obj2`.

```
class One{
    int a=10;

    void print_changed_data(){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
 
class Two extends One {
    void update(){
        super.a=20;
    }
}

class Three extends One {

}

public class four{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        One obj1 = new One();
        obj1.print_changed_data(); // Prints 10

        Two obj2 = new Two();
        obj2.print_changed_data(); // Prints 10
        obj2.update();
        obj2.print_changed_data(); // Prints 20

        Three obj3 = new Three();
        obj3.print_changed_data(); // Prints 10
    }
}
```

In the above example I have amended your code and created 3 objects `obj1`, `obj2` and `obj3`. `obj1` and `obj3` will always print out 10 when you call `print_changed_data()` because you haven't updated `a` with a new value yet. Whereas calling `update()` on `obj2` you are changing `obj2`s `a` value to 20.

Check out this simple [w3schools guide for inheritance](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_inheritance.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Classes are just blueprints; they don't have any storage. When you initialize a class, an object is created with all the variables needed. `obj2` and `obj3` are just different objects in memory containing their separate variables. There isn't a 'direct' connection between `class two` and `class three`. Both classes use `class one` as a blueprint, but that doesn't create a relationship between the variables (`a`) in the objects.

Imagine a company builds cars from the exact blueprint; the vehicles are technically the same, but if you start one car, only that actual car will turn. All other vehicles from this precise blueprint won't start; it would be weird if they turned on.